# Which one is a better use of new Set() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
const array = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5]

// first case
const filteredArray1 = new Set([...array])
 
// second case
const filteredArray2 = [...new Set(array)]

console.log(filteredArray1, filteredArray2)
```

Comment: The first case gives you a set, the second case gives you an array

Comment: There is no need to shallow copy the array as `[...array]` when calling the `Set` constructor. But anyway the two variables are of a different type (Set and Array), so you cannot really compare.

Comment: You get two different results here, so it's hard to say which is "better". But the first one definitely creates a useless array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const filteredArray2 = [...new Set(array)]

console.log(filteredArray1, filteredArray2)

// This is  much suitable way of doing it since you'll be directly getting the type of the new variable as an array. In the first method you have the chance of getting the type as a set or an object.
```